# MySQL Group data by name of day in last week

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query to group the last 7 days worth of stats data by weekday and return the following:

```
    dayname | count(*)
-----------------------
Monday      |   3              
Tuesday     |   2
```

The **above is my desired output** however I can't seem to get the dayname.

```
    Day(enquiries.created_at) | Count(enquiries.id)
-----------------------------------------------------
    1                         | 1
    3                         | 1
    4                         | 14
    31                        | 5
```

The **above is my current output** and an explanation is that 31st August, 1st September etc... however I want to group by weekday name as opposed to date.

Here is the query that I have so far:

```
SELECT Day(enquiries.created_at), 
       Count(enquiries.id) 
FROM   enquiry_stats 
       LEFT JOIN enquiries 
              ON enquiry_stats.enquiry_id = enquiries.id 
WHERE  created_at >= Date_add(Curdate(), INTERVAL -7 day) 
GROUP  BY Day(enquiries.created_at);
```

**I am just wondering how to group the data not by day but by dayname?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"I am just wondering how to group the data not by **day** but by **dayname**?"

As easy as it will sound, use [`DAYNAME()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayname-function.php) instead:

```
SELECT DayName(enquiries.created_at), 
       Count(enquiries.id) 
FROM   enquiry_stats 
       LEFT JOIN enquiries 
              ON enquiry_stats.enquiry_id = enquiries.id 
WHERE  created_at >= Date_add(Curdate(), INTERVAL -7 day) 
GROUP  BY DayName(enquiries.created_at);
```